# I need to separate AJAX call to do two different things

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, express, formidable

I need my ajax call to send two separate calls. One for the file and one for the JSON data. Then, I am trying to have NODE.JS upload the file, return the destination and that inside the JSON data on the server side.

Here is my **AJAX**:

```
                uploadAttachments: function(commentArray, success, error) { 

                    $(commentArray).each(function(index, commentJSON) {
                    console.log(commentJSON.File);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080',
                        data: commentJSON.file + JSON.stringify(commentJSON),
                        success: function(commentJSON) {
                            success(commentJSON)
                        },
                        error: error
                    });
                    });
                }
```

Here is my **NODE**:

```
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        // get the temporary location of the file
        var tmp_path = req.files.thumbnail.path;
        // set where the file should actually exists - in this case it is in the "images" directory
        var target_path = '/uploads' + req.files.thumbnail.name;
        // move the file from the temporary location to the intended location
        fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // delete the temporary file, so that the explicitly set temporary upload dir does not get filled with unwanted files
            fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path + ' - ' + req.files.thumbnail.size + ' bytes');
            });
        });
        req.on('data', function(chunk) {
               var element; 
               try {
                   element = JSON.parse(chunk);
               } catch(err) {
                   console.log(err);
               }
            fs.readFile("comments-data.json", 'utf8', function(err, json) {
                var array = JSON.parse(json);
                array.push(element);
                fs.writeFile("comments-data.json", JSON.stringify(array), function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log("The file was saved!");
                });
            });
            res.end('{"msg": "success"}');
        });
    };
```

I've tried several different variations and alternate scripts. Part of my issue is, that this is using a JQuery plugin. I don't understand how the data should be sent.

The documentation says something like this:

```
        // Create form data
        var formData = new FormData();
        $(Object.keys(commentJSON)).each(function(index, key) {
            var value = commentJSON[key];
            if(value) formData.append(key, value);
        });
```

But I don't know how to parse that with node.js and split it up there either.

Comment: Are you sure that a comments-plugin support text and upload at the same time? If anybody want to play with it then runnable project is http://sgeproject.narod.ru/node/efc.zip

Comment: Well the documentation says to do it above, therefore, I assume it is both. @AikonMogwai

Comment: If I understand right [ https://github.com/Viima/jquery-comments/blob/master/js/jquery-comments.js#L1513 ] that this plugin don't support image and text in one message together, but separately does. I update demo  http://sgeproject.narod.ru/node/efc2.zip As you can see: one route to add image or text; also image upload is work.

Comment: Wow thanks @AikonMogwai. That seemed to work. However when you upload something it does not save that inside the JSON data. I'm also having a little bit of trouble implementing it inside my code.